# Class is not abstract and does not over ride error

Tags: mouseevent, overriding, abstract-class, mouselistener

I'm trying to write a program which tests reaction times by clicking on a circle when it changes color but can't get the clicking portion working. I keep getting the error that my class is not abstract and does not over ride the methods in MouseListener. Here is the code.

```
            import java.util.*;
            import java.io.*;
            import java.awt.*;
            import java.awt.event.*;
            import java.util.Random;
            import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
            import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
            import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

            public class Stopwatch
            {
                public static int windowX = 900; 
                public static int windowY = 700;

                public static void main(String args[])
                {
                    GfxApp gfx = new GfxApp();
                    gfx.setSize(900,700);
                    gfx.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {public void
                    windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {System.exit(0);}});
                    gfx.show();
                }
            }

            class GfxApp extends Frame
            {
                public void paint(Graphics g) 
                {           
                    Timer.drawgreen(g);
                    Timer.pause();
                    Timer.drawred(g);

                }
            }

            class Timer
            {
                public static int circlex = 300;
                public static int circley = 200;
                public static int radius = 250;

                public static void drawgreen(Graphics g)
                {
                    g.setColor(new Color(0,255,0));
                    g.fillOval(circlex, circley, radius, radius);
                }

                public static void drawred(Graphics g)
                {
                    g.setColor(new Color(255,0,0));
                    g.fillOval(circlex, circley, radius, radius);
                }

                public static void pause()
                {
                    Random rand = new Random();

                    int k = rand.nextInt(301);

                    for(double i = 0; i < 500 + k; i += .000001)
                    {
            //                      delay
                    }
                }
            }

            class Mouse implements MouseListener
            {
                MouseListener circle = new MouseListener();

                public void MouseClicked (MouseEvent me)
                {
                }
                public void MouseEntered (MouseEvent me)
                {
                }
                public void MouseExited (MouseEvent me)
                {
                }
                public void MousePressed (MouseEvent me)
                {
                }
                public void MouseReleased (MouseEvent me)
                {
                }
            }
```

Comment: I did what McKeown said and have this error. 

MouseListener is abstract; cannot be instantiated
    MouseListener circle = new MouseListener();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation methods do not match the case of the interface, therefore the compiler considers your class not satisfying the contract and suggests that this class be marked as abstract.

For example, the interface defines this method:

```
void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { }
```

You have it as:  (capital M instead of lower m)

```
void MouseClicked (MouseEvent me) { }
```

This line here confuses me:

```
MouseListener circle = new MouseListener();
```

From what I see `MouseListener` is an interface, you can certainly have the left side declaring the type as an interface but the right side must be a concrete class.

Comment: After changing that I still get this error. MouseListener is abstract; cannot be instantiated
    MouseListener circle = new MouseListener();

Comment: what is `MouseListener` other than an interface?  You can't create an instance of an interface, your example shows no *class* named `MouseListener`